# ASP.NET Core sticky sessions on IIS

Tags: iis, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, load-balancing, kestrel-http-server

I want to publish my asp.net core apps on IIS, i.e. IIS as reverse-proxy and Core running on 1-n Kestrels.

I've been reading about Sessions and caching in .net core. For Sessions it is apparently recommended that in-memory caching is used only in dev/test, and I suppose the reason is because of an assumption that sticky-sessions wouldn't be available.

However, can IIS provide sticky sessions i.e. all requests from one session are routed to the same Kestrel, therefore in-memory Sessions should be fine by me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are deploying to a single machine, using in-memory sessions would be ok, and if a test site is on a single machine that would be ok.

If you are going to deploy across a web farm etc, in-memory sessions won't work and you will need to find a solution for distributed session storage.
If this is the case, you may as well implement this and test like for like.

This post shows you how to setup in-memory sessions: https://www.exceptionnotfound.net/finding-and-using-asp-net-session-in-core-1-0/

basically settings:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)  
{
    ...
    services.AddMemoryCache();
    services.AddSession(options =>
    {
        options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60);
        options.CookieName = ".MyCoreApp";
    });
    ...
}
```

and

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerfactory)  
{
    ...
    app.UseSession();
    ...
}
```

then calling SetString and GetString:

```
Context.Session.SetString("UserName", "John Smith");
var userName = Context.Session.GetString("UserName");
```

You can look at the following for storing session in SQL Server.
http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/292/configuring-sql-server-for-session-state-in-asp-net-core-1-0-mvc

Comment: Thanks Mark, great answer! Still querying about the IIS as reverse-proxy part, could it be configured for sticky-sessions?

Comment: Not sure what you mean there? The session state will be available per session, as long as the session is alive for the same client calling it? Can you provide some more info?

Comment: Ok so traditionally I have had load-balancers using sticky-sessions, so they always redirect the call to the same server. This way sessions could be stored in-memory only, and not require the distributed cache to be used. So if IIS (my "load-balancer" for Kestrel) would support sticky-sessions, then a distributed cache would not be needed?

Comment: I see, not sure, I would probably just implement distributed cache anyways, its pretty seamless and may save hassles later.